# Add or delete rows of textInput

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm looking for ways to add / delete rows of `textInput` in R Shiny. The desired output is similar to the image below:

[image]

Image credits: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/snippets/preview.php?topic=bootstrap&file=table-with-add-and-delete-row-feature

The desired output is not necessarily a table. Alternatively, when the user clicks "Add" a list containing same number of blank `textInput` entries as the previous row (user cannot add more columns) should appear. When the user clicks "Delete", the corresponding row should be removed. It is important to be able to **capture the user input from each text box**. Is there a way to accomplish this easily using R Shiny?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("input_no",
                        "Number of inputs:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 5,
                        value = 30),
            uiOutput("dateinputs")
        ),

        mainPanel(
           verbatimTextOutput("res")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$dateinputs <- renderUI({
        no <- as.integer(input$input_no) 
        lapply(1:no, function(i) {
            
            textInput(paste0("ind", i),
                      label = paste("Textinput ", i))
        })
    })
    
    report_dates <- reactive({
        no <- as.integer(input$input_no) 
        
        sapply(1:no, function(i) {
            input[[paste0("ind", i)]]
        })
    })
    
    output$res <- renderPrint({
        report_dates()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Another option is to use the edit function of DT:

Have a look at this example: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html (Section 2.4). You could create an actionButton() to add rows and edit them in the table

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I implemented something similar using lapply to return list with same number of `textInput` objects as the previous row. The advantage is that each input can be accessed using `input[[paste0("ind", i, "_" j)]]`, where i refers to the row and j refers to the column. The catch is that there is no upper limit on the number of rows, so using a `sliderInput` will not solve the problem. I'm looking for a more concise implementation.

Comment: DT may be able to solve the problem. The problem is: each 'Delete Row' button should be labeled distinctly using apply and a `observeEvent` should be defined to observe click of each `input[[paste0("delete_", i)]]`. The code becomes very messy even with DT. It's even worse with list of `textInput`